# How to manage empty IN sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in = implode(',',$ids);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id IN ($in) ";
```

Query works no problem. But when `$ids` is empty array `$ids = array();`

I got sql query error rightly so because `SELECT * FROM user where user_id IN ()` is not a valid query .

How  can I avoid such situation without checking for empty array i.e making query run no matter what ?

Comment: Why not just check for empty array? MySQL just awaits some parameters after IN, so I guess there is no way

Comment: I hope `$ids` are not user-provided and if, you escape them properly, before inserting them into your query.

Comment: I have a situation where I cannot check for empty array . I had to make query run without error . All I can do is change input parameter . Query runs return result zero is ok for me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty IN clause parameter list in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210233/empty-in-clause-parameter-list-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way to manage this is:

```
$in = implode("','",$ids); // generate like 1','2
$query = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id IN ('$in') "; //  if has  1','2 surrond it with quote make it IN('1','2') and if empty than IN('')
```

This saves you from if/else structure and everything else

Comment: In some cases, the column could content an empty value, and this solution will return all empty values. This could happen in a foreign key column, for instance.

Comment: If user_id  is unique identifier, it throws Conversion failed error.

Comment: While this is obviously a clever solution, it's confusing and not really intuitive. You have to understand a lot to read this. The anser of @faizan-ali is better in that regard.

Answer (score 8):

you should not run the query when the $in is empty. I think what yoou need is something like this

```
$in = implode(',',$ids);
if($in) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id IN ($in) ";
 }
 else {
      //alternate scenario here
 }
```

**Edit**

```
$in = implode("','",$ids); // generate like 1','2
$query = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id IN ('$in') "; //  if has  1','2 surrond it with quote make it IN('1','2') and if empty than IN('')
```

Comment: How do you know that the query shouldn't be executed without a condition if `$ids` is empty? Also, SQL injection?

Comment: because if $in is empty the sql will throw an exception as explained in the question

Comment: I didn't ask why it *will not* be executed, but why it *should not* be executed. How do you know the OP doesn't want to select all users in that case?

Comment: I have a situation where I cannot check for empty array . I had to make query run without error . All I can do is change input parameter . Query runs return result zero is ok for me

Comment: Falcon has posted the answer below which is the best solution for this situtation

Answer (score 5):

you can add 0 ahead of $ids string. After all No ids will start from 0 in any database.

Or you can do like this..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where ".($ids != ''? "user_id IN ($ids)" : " 1=1");
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually always add an "invalid" value, so the list is never empty:

```
$in = implode(',', array_merge($ids, [-1])); // never empty!
```

No additional conditional statements are required, keeping the code relatively clean.
The "invalid" value must be outside the range of allowed values, of course.
(The example above assumes that valid `$ids` are always positive.)

Comment: Honestly, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((count($in)>0)
{
  //execute sql query code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for the given query you should not run it at all.

```
if ($ids) {
  // run your code
} else {
  return false; //or whatever.
}
```

for the other cases it could be conditional concatenation as shown in the other answers

Answer (score -1):

I do several different types of checking in different situations to make sure that the sql statement is valid.
In the most basic type of checking,  I make sure that the variable is not empty or false

```
$in = implode(',',$ids);
if(!$ids) $in="0";
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN ($ids)";
```

Typically, I use a whole series of `db_*` functions which validate the input I pass into queries so that I can handle more advanced uses check where the `$ids` array comes from

Here is some test code that works well for me in dozens of situations.

```
function db_number_list($lst)
{
    if(!$lst) 
        return "0"; // if there are no passed in values , return a 0 
    if (!is_array($lst)) 
        $lst = explode (",",$lst);  //if a lst was passed in,  create an array
    foreach ($lst as $k=>$val)
    {
        if(!is_numeric(trim($val)))
            unset($lst[$k]);//remove non-numeric values;
    }
    if(!count($lst)) 
        return "0"; //if nothing is in the array after removing non-numeric values,  return 0
    return implode (",",$lst);
} 

$ids=array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (".db_number_list($ids).")";
echo "ids:'".print_r($ids,true)."'<br>$query<hr>";

$ids="1,2,45,6,";
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (".db_number_list($ids).")";
echo "ids:'".print_r($ids,true)."'<br>$query<hr>";

$ids=array(3,6,1,"drop table x", 4);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (".db_number_list($ids).")";
echo "ids:'".print_r($ids,true)."'<br>$query<hr>";
```

Output:

```
ids:'Array ( ) '
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (0)
```

---

```
ids:'1,2,45,6,'
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (1,2,45,6)
```

---

```
ids:'Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 1 [3] => drop table x [4] => 4 ) '
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN (3,6,1,4)
```

---

Answer (score -2):

You should set a conditional concatenation:

```
if (count($ids) > 0)
{
    $in = implode(',',$ids);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id IN ($in)";
    // ....
}
```

EDIT: fixed my misunderstanding.