# Empty IN clause parameter list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, in-clause

What happens when you do a SQL query where the `IN` clause is empty?

For example:

```
SELECT user WHERE id IN ();
```

Will MySQL handle this as expected (that is, always false), and if not, how can my application handle this case when building the `IN` clause dynamically?

Comment: The id column value is clearly not in an empty set, since nothing is in an empty set. Also, it turns out that is incorrect syntax. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/2412

Comment: Just don't execute the query if you've "built" (or ascertained) an empty `IN` clause.  Sheesh!

Comment: @LoztInSpace Its many times useful to have a single query, even if it has OR conditions, rather than writing a query builder logic in another language. So, it is annoying that IN doesn't handle empty lists. (:ids is null or id in :ids) would be great, rather than using another language to leave out the IN part when :ids is null . Evaluate to false would have been nice rather than throwing syntax errors.

Answer (score 87):

If I have an application where I'm building the `IN` list dynamically, and it might end up empty, what I sometimes do is initialize the list with an impossible value and add to that. E.g. if it's a list of usernames, I'll start with an empty string, since that's not a possible username. If it's an auto_increment ID, I'll use -1 because the actual values are always positive.

If this isn't feasible because there are no impossible values, you have to use a conditional to decide whether to include `AND column IN ($values)` expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Anyone give us some SQL reasoning here? As OP says the intuitive behavior would be to always evaluate as false.

Comment: It's just a syntax issue -- they didn't want to allow empty lists.

Comment: If `column IN (1, 2, 3)` is equivalent to `column=1 OR column=2 OR column=3`, then it is natural that an empty list would be equivalent to zero `OR` terms. But this leads to weird rules if you try to combine it with other boolean expressions. For example, should `<expr> AND column IN (1,2,3)` map to `<expr> AND (true)`? But that seems wrong, if intuitively you would say `column IN ()` should be **false**.

Comment: Damn I spent a good couple hours wondering why this doesn't work, only to learn that `IN` queries don't work with empty sets!! Thank you @Barmar

Comment: @BillKarwin It depends on how that list of values corresponds to the application semantics. For instance, if this is a form specifying filters, and you don't select anything from that form field, it usually means "any value", not "no value" (because that would filter out everything).

Answer (score 28):

This gives me 0 results as well:

```
SELECT id FROM User
WHERE id IN (NULL);
```

Tried on MYSQL 5.6

Comment: This can be problematic because `id IN (NULL)` evaluates to `NULL` and not `FALSE`. That's mostly a problem for `NOT IN`: `SELECT id FROM User WHERE id NOT IN (NULL);` will return 0 results as well.

Comment: Very interesting! In lament terms (NULL) is not an empty set of values.

Answer (score 12):

The closest approximation of this query with valid syntax is:

```
SELECT user FROM tbl1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE FALSE);
```

which unconditionally returns an empty result set. The subquery in the bracket always returns an empty set, and no value can be found in an empty set, since an empty set contains no values.

Comment: Another subquery which returns an empty set is `(select top 0 0)`, which has the advantage of not requiring a table name.

Comment: This doesn't really help in the case where you're generating a literal `IN` list dynamically. He's not looking for a way to produce a vacuous `IN` clause, he wants to know how to deal with it when it happens accidentally because he's given an empty array of values.

Comment: or simply `SELECT user FROM tbl1 WHERE id IN (FALSE)`

Comment: @NicolaPedretti That assumes `id` isn't a boolean field, which is probably a reasonable assumption, but an assumption nevertheless.

Comment: The question specifies MySQL and `SELECT TOP N` isn't MySQL. On the other hand `(SELECT 0 WHERE 0)` works.  However, doing `IN (SELECT ...)` seems to create a *dependent subquery* in MySQL 5.7 (as shown in `explain`) and the resulting query is extremely slow.

Comment: @benrwb Even better: `(select top 0 NULL)`, which should work with any column type.

Comment: For MySQL you can do `IN (select NULL from (select 0) x where FALSE)`

Answer (score 8):

Use an always false statement

Before creating the SQL, check for the array size. 
If the size is 0, generate the where statement as `1 = 2`, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name in ()
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE 1 = 2
```

For "not in" on an empty array, generate an always true statement as in:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name not in ()
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE 1 = 1
```

This should work for more complex queries as:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (name in () OR name = 'Alice')
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (1 = 2 OR name = 'Alice')
```

Comment: This is really great solution. I've just implemented this into my PHP framework. Thank You!

Comment: Well, I could actually just `WHERE true` and `WHERE false` in that case, or am I missing something. Both approaches are not ideal when dynamically building queries though.

Answer (score 5):

If you use AUTO_INCREMENT for id (1,2,3, ..) and if array is empty, you can add one item [0]. So it will be

```
if (empty($arr)) {
   $arr[] = 0;
}

SELECT user WHERE id IN (0);
```

And there will be no mysql parse error. This case is very usefull in subqueries - when your main query is not dependent on subquery results.

---

Better way - don't call the query if array is empty.

```
$data = null;
if (!empty($arr)) {
    $data = ... call query
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't leave IN operator empty, you must put into it something, `NULL` for example. But even, in this case, it will be not working as expected, because comparing with `NULL` always returns `NULL` (empty). One possible solution is to add a subselect.

Example:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users;

+-----------+
| user_id   |
+-----------+
|      1000 |
|      1001 |
|      1002 |
|      1003 |
|      1004 |
|      1005 |
|      1006 |
|      1007 |
|      1008 |
|      1009 |
|      1010 |
+-----------+

SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN ();
ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN (NULL);
Empty set (0.0003 sec)    

SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1001, 1002, 1003) 
AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id IN (NULL));
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|    1001 |
|    1002 |
|    1003 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.0004 sec)
```

You cal a little bit modify (shorten) queries, but I think, they also will a little more slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another variation of always false statement for empty lists that preserves both logic and the notion of actual column in the query.

Incorrect `id in ()` can be rewritten into:

```
where id <> id;
```

Similarly incorrect negative condition `id not in ()` can be transformed by custom query building code into:

```
where id = id;
```

This approach is safer than [`id not in (NULL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37419910/603516) as it doesn't evaluate to NULL.

But beware that this would filter out of the result the rows where `id is null`. This may be considered a feature in some cases.

Espesially useful with complex stacked query building logic where nested builder is not aware how the resulting subquery could be used above.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this:

`SELECT user WHERE id in (SELECT 1 WHERE 1!=1)`

There could be a need to replace 1 with a value of the appropriate data type as mentioned in a comment by @JamesHoux.
An assumption made here is that a user's id is an int.

Comment: Suggested tweak: (SELECT NULL WHERE 1!=1).  Using NULL will make an empty type-agnostic set that is comparable to columns of any type.  If you use a literal like the number 1, then an empty set of integers is created. The database engine may error if it can't compare type 'integer' to your desired column type.

Comment: That is pretty smart!

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like I may have been wrong about the reliability of that approach. I am using this with NpgSQL in C# and the NpgsqlCommand.Prepare() method throws an exception saying it can't comparing "text" to "bigint".  In this case a bigint is being compared to the empty array. Apparently the empty array is being created as type "text". :(   I guess there's no magic bullet.

Comment: OK, good to know. Does SELECT 1 fix it for you?

Comment: Oh yeah, most definitely.   Comparing a bigint to 1 works.  I had to write a type-checking function to determine the db value type to generate a SELECT statement with a correct placeholder value.  Its unfortunate that that SELECT statement is not type-agnostic, but other than that its still a very good approach with the additional type handling logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you still need to run the query when your `IN` is empty; for example with `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND IN ()`.

As you are already dynamically building the `IN` in the application layer, I'd handle the empty case there.

Here's a basic example in PHP

```
$condition = 'FALSE' // Could feasibly want TRUE under different circumstances
if($values){
   $inParams = **dynamically generated IN parameters from $values**;
   $condition = 'IN (' . $inParams . ')';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE '.$condition;
```

If you don't need to run the query with an empty `IN`, then don't; save yourself a trip to the database!

**N.B.** In case you aren't already, I'd build/use a function that goes the long way round and binds in your `IN` parameters properly, rather than just concatting them raw into the SQL. This will give you some protection against SQL injection if it's used on raw data.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using that query in an application and you pass dynamically a list of objects to the query, I should not call to the database to do a select with an impossible value, I should return an empty list without calling to the database query, directly.

Because it has no sense to do a query that you know that is empty before calling it.

Comment: Avoiding the trivially empty query might be premature optimization.