# cakephp 3 - Impossible to generate condition with empty list

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.7

In cakephp 3 query gives error when added 'IN' condition in contain query.

```
$itemsquery = $Students->find('all');
$itemsquery->select(['Students.id']);

$itemsquery->matching('CategoriesStudents');
$itemsquery->contain([
'CategoriesStudents' => function ($q) use ($category_ids) {
return $q->where(['CategoriesStudents.category_id IN' => $category_ids]);
}
]);

// debug($itemsquery);
$items = $itemsquery->toArray();
```

Error

```
Impossible to generate condition with empty list of values for field (`CategoriesStudents`.`category_id`)

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
An Internal Server Error Occurred
```

Tables are

1. categories_students

category_id, student_id

2. students
3. category

$category_ids array

```
Array
(
    [1] => 57
    [2] => 60
    [3] => 58
    [4] => 13
    [5] => 78
    [6] => 56
    [7] => 59
    [8] => 79
    [9] => 95
    [10] => 94
    [11] => 96
    [12] => 93
    [13] => 82
    [14] => 23
    [15] => 82
    [16] => 14
    [17] => 16
    [18] => 101
    [19] => 14
)
```

Please help

Comment: You are saying that `$category_ids` contains these values, but the query builder says otherwise, and I'm inclined to belive the query builder, unless you can come up with an example that reproduces the error despite the values being provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can't leave `IN` operator empty, you must put into it something like `NULL`. Try to cover the case for an empty Array:

```
return $q->where(
     ['CategoriesStudents.category_id IN' =>
        count($category_ids) > 0 ?  $category_ids : [null])
]);
```

Reference:
[Empty IN clause parameter list in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210233/empty-in-clause-parameter-list-in-mysql)