# Empty in expression cause an exception in native query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use `Hibernate` and `JpaRepository` to handle my DB operations.

I have this query (to simplify because original query is quite big):

```java
@Query(value="select * from history h where h.project_id in :projects", nativeQuery=true)
List<History> getHistoriesByProjectsIn(@Param("projects")List<Long> projects);
```

and it is working when I pass valid and not empty `List<Long>`. However when I pass empty list which may happen and it is not unusual in my scenario I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgresql documentation [states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20560): `in` predicate can not hold empty list

```
expression IN (value [, ...])
```

and as hibernate passes the native queries as is, it's predictable that this leads to a problem.

But as workaround you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210590/6277104) suggestion: *initialize the list with an impossible value*.

**EDIT**

Actually, this behaviour was changed in hibernate 5.4.10. See the [commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/internal/QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java#L646):

```
SHA-1: ab9ae431858dc6727023d7f03bd6925f99011c62

* HHH-8901 replace "in ()" SQL with "in (null)" in QueryParameterBindingsImpl
```

And for your case the following sql will be generated:

```sql
select * from history h where h.project_id in (null)
```

It looks strange that the task [HHH-8901](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8901) description completely irrelevant to these changes.

Comment: actually I have found a solution to my problem already. hibernate v5.4.21 fix this issue so update of hibernate is just enough

Comment: I am surprised that this is an issue. This is just invalid sql as postgresql documentation states. Hibernate just passed the `native query` directly to the jdbc driver. And by the way as stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate) the empty list is also prohibited for the hql/jpql queries.

Comment: Actually this behavior was changed in hibernate 5.4.10, see my updated answer.