# Error in SQL Syntax while trying to convert database

Tags: php, mysql

I got an Error while trying to convert my database.

> Fehler in 163 - 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
>   Query war : SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE user_active = 1 AND user_id NOT IN ()

My Code:

```
$e0 = query("SELECT * FROM ".$phpbb_prefix."_users
    WHERE user_active = 1 AND user_id NOT IN (".implode("','", $ilch_to_phpbb).")" , $phpbb_con)
    or die('Fehler in '. __LINE__ . ' - '.mysql_errno($phpbb_con) . ' : '. mysql_error($phpbb_con).'<br /> Query war : ' . $lastquery . '<hr />');
```

I can not recognize the error. Any Ideas?

- **Database:** MySQL(i) 5.5.53-0+deb7u1
- **PHP:** 5

Comment: Well, the `in` clause is empty, which isn't valid syntax in any database...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to manage empty IN sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481334/how-to-manage-empty-in-sql-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage empty IN sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481334/how-to-manage-empty-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your implode. Imagine if `$ilch_to_phpbb` contains 2 user id's, the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM ".$phpbb_prefix."_users
WHERE user_active = 1 AND user_id NOT IN (2','3)
```

That's obviously invalid SQL syntax.

You either need to drop the `'` in the implode (although this will cause a SQL error if `$ilch_to_phpbb` is empty, because `NOT IN ()` is invalid SQL), or add `'` around it in the query:

```
AND user_id NOT IN ('".implode("','", $ilch_to_phpbb)."')
```

Comment: `WHERE user_active = 1 AND user_id NOT IN ('".implode("','", $ilch_to_phpbb)."')" , $phpbb_con)`  causes:  Fehler in 163 - 1054 : Unknown column 'user_active' in 'where clause'
Query war : SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE user_active = 1 AND user_id NOT IN ('')

Comment: That's a different problem. That means there is no column "user_active" in your "phpbb_users" table.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved now. Last error was caused by phpbb3. There is no Column User_active. There now is User_Type. 0 for active, 1 for inactive 2 for ignore and 3 for founder.